# cycle inside a thread

Tags: c, multithreading, cycle

I created 100 threads

```
int i;
pthread_t threads[100];

for(i=0; i<100; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, analisa, (void*)vetor_local[i]);
```

but when I do this cycle inside the function used by the threads

```
void* analisa(void* arg)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    char *local1 = (char*) arg;
    passa_automovel((void*) local1);
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

It only calls the function `passa_automovel` 100 times instead of 300. I put a counter in `passa_automovel`and it only counted 100 calls.

This is the full code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

#define POSTOS_CONTROLO 100
#define CARROS 300

typedef struct
{
  int velocidade;
  char matricula[20];
  char local[50];
} controlo;

controlo postos_controlo[CARROS];
controlo infracoes[CARROS];
char vetor_local[POSTOS_CONTROLO][50];
pthread_mutex_t mux;
int cont_controlo = 0, cont_infracoes = 0, multas_processadas = 0;
pthread_cond_t cond_multa;

void* passa_multa(void* arg)
{

  /*garantir exclusao mutua no acesso a variavel de condiçao e ao contador*/
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mux);
  while (cont_controlo != cont_infracoes)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond_multa, &mux);

  infracoes[cont_infracoes] = postos_controlo[cont_controlo];
  multas_processadas++;

  /*liberta zona de exclusao mutua*/
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mux);

  pthread_exit(NULL );
}

void* passa_automovel(void* arg)
{

  char *local1 = (char*) arg;
  time_t t;
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
  int i_matricula, velocidade;

  i_matricula = rand() % 900;
  char matricula[15];
  sprintf(matricula, "%d", i_matricula);

  velocidade = rand() % 120;

  /*garantir exclusao mutua no acesso a variavel de condiçao e ao contador*/
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mux);

  postos_controlo[cont_controlo].velocidade = velocidade;
  strcpy(postos_controlo[cont_controlo].matricula, matricula);
  strcpy(postos_controlo[cont_controlo].local, local1);

  if (velocidade > 70)
  {
    cont_infracoes++;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond_multa);

  }

  cont_controlo++;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mux);

  pthread_exit(NULL );
}

void* analisa(void* arg)
{
  int i;
  //char *local1=(char*)arg;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    char *local1 = (char*) arg;
    passa_automovel((void*) local1);
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL );
}

int main()
{

  int i;
  pthread_t threads[POSTOS_CONTROLO], multa_thread;

  /*preencher o vetor de locais*/
  for (i = 0; i < POSTOS_CONTROLO; i++)
  {
    char str[15];
    sprintf(str, "%d", i);
    strcpy(vetor_local[i], str);
  }

  pthread_cond_init(&cond_multa, NULL );

  /*lancar postos de controlo (threads)*/
  for (i = 0; i < POSTOS_CONTROLO; i++)
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, analisa, (void*) vetor_local[i]);

  /*criar thread passa multa*/
  pthread_create(&multa_thread, NULL, passa_multa, NULL );

  /*esperar que threads terminem execucao*/
  for (i = 0; i < POSTOS_CONTROLO; i++)
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL );

  for (i = 0; i < CARROS; i++)
  {
    printf("%d velocidade: %d   matricula: %s      local: %s    \n", i,
        postos_controlo[i].velocidade, postos_controlo[i].matricula,
        postos_controlo[i].local);

    //printf("multas: %d \n", infracoes[i].velocidade);

  }

  printf("multas passadas: %d \n", cont_infracoes);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you use a mutex when counting?

Comment: Show us the code of `passa_automovel` and a complete working/reproducible example. For example, Is your counting therein threadsafe? When/where/how do you observe this counter? Do you properly wait for all your threads to finish (e.g. pthread_join())? Maybe your program exists, before all threads have finished. There are a number of options. Hard to tell without a complete working example.

Comment: Or better - can we have the code for `passa_automovel`? It is probably not thread-safe and thus you are getting weird results.

Comment: Regardless to the question, passing `(void*)vector_local[i]` is casting the value in place i. I think what you wanted is `(void*)&vector_local[i]`

Comment: @ HAL9000 I used a mutex, also I printed the results in `postos_controlo` and it was empty from positions 100 to 299. Except for `velocidade`, that was 0 from positions 100 to 299.

Comment: No wonder you assessed the situation wrongly, you say you have counters for function calls, but the counters are elsewhere...

Comment: @Karoly Horvath deleted them, they were for debugging

Comment: Btw: The code shown misses to join `multa_thread`.

Comment: @HAL9000 do you know why it does not have values for `velocidade` `matricula` or `local` after position 99?

Comment: wait I was wrong. The problem is interesting now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. You are calling pthread_exit inside passa_automovel.
In this way you are killing the thread at the first cycle.
Remove it and it works.

Comment: In this context it might be worth mentioning that calling `pthread_exit()` is necessary only, if the function wants to return a pointer to the joining thread. In all other cases just leaving the thread function using `return NULL` is perfectly valid.